# How to use multi opensource chef-server?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to control all client nodes with multi chef-server.
As on its website, they only have a package of one chef-server installation.

If I want to manage multi chef-server with high availability, how can I separate out database and other component in chef-server system and putting replications of them in other different servers?

Answer (score 3):

There is no official HA support in open source chef. This is a feature of private chef, opscode's commercial offering.

Personally I question the need for HA. If you chef server goes off-line the servers it manages will continue to run unaffected. Instead I would recommend focusing on DR, the ability to recover my chef server in the event of an outage.

"Cookbooks", "environments", "roles" and "databags" are normally kept under revision control. What's missing for DR is the transactional data namely "nodes" and "clients". For these I'd recommend investigating the new [download](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_download.html) and [upload](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_upload.html) knife commands that came with Chef 11.

Comment: It will be cumbersome if we don't have a way to config multiple chef-server. To think that we need to manually build a new chef-server, download, upload cookbook, get all client nodes up pointing to the new one and have their data in it again, that's too many things.

I hope there is a way to change some configuration in an opensource chef-server to separate each components.

Comment: @A-letubby Purchase a licence for private chef. This is the opscode "value add" that is perhaps worth paying for? Alternatively develop automation to manage your open source chef instances. In fairness opscode have done a good job in streamlining the install.

Comment: Looking at http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_chef_server.html, I am thinking that the base code between opensource one and private one might not be different and private one they are just providing an easier way over these based configurations.

Comment: And yes, I am also thinking about using private chef but it's not that easy at my working place as I am not having the final decision. And it's likely not to be the private one.

Answer (score 2):

I have spoken with some guys at Chef about this and technically it is possible to run an Opensource Chef in an HA configuration.  The Omnibus installation of Chef Server installs postgres, solr, nginx, etc. You can potentially break out some of these services into separate servers.  Also the cookbook storage is actually mimicking S3, so you could just point it at actual S3 instead.  If you look at the [optional settings](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_chef_server_optional_settings.html) page you will see you can change a lot of what the application expects as well as where to direct certain API calls.  While this is not supported, if you have the resources, you may be able to get this to work.  As with everything else in technology YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Quite useful. Actually, I have tried the different way myself several month ago easily. By just building 2 chef-server and sync-up both of their PostgreSQL together and having Linux-HA to switch passive to active one if current active chef-server goes down. Here is the link I documented (http://blog.parnurzeal.com/experimental-ha-for-opensource-chef-server/).

Comment: Thanks for blogging this.  Its definitely a useful case.

Comment: I will try the link you gave me some time and see if it works.